# How to locate this element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to locate the "NEXT" button. Locating by class name is not working because there is other element with the same class name. This button has no ID.

I tried locating by xpath>>contains text etc and it works. But it's not the perfect way, due to possible future translation of the site and the "NEXT" text may seem quite another...
It is about 2 last lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YbPK.jpg

```
from time import sleep

import self as self
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get("https://cct-103.firebaseapp.com/")

try:
    checkin = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label")))
    checkin.click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    checkin = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiButton-label")))
    checkin.click()

locator = (By.ID, "guestName")
guest_input = driver.find_element(*locator)
guest_input.send_keys("xyz")

 next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'NEXT')]")     
 next_button.click()
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/N6RK4Hh

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and the following locator option.

```
next_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(., 'NEXT')]")))
next_button.click()
```

Sometimes you might get intercepted exception.

```
 next_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(., 'NEXT')]")))
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
```

**Updated the code with Css selector.**

```
next_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.MuiButtonBase-root")))
next_button.click()
```

Or

```
next_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.MuiButtonBase-root")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
```

Comment: Checkin and guest_input works properly. The problem is with "NEXT" button. I don't want to locate it by text which this button contains because this site can be translated in future. And the "next" text will change to German (or other language) version of this word. How to locate this "NEXT" button?

Comment: @Virtual107 : try now the updated css selector and let me know.

Comment: You are right, I could locate it using CSS Selector. May I use simple "Next_button.click()" instead of "driver.execute.....". What is actually the difference?

Comment: Yes you can do simple click that was I have mentioned.However sometimes you might get intercepted exception if you get then you can use driver.execute option.

Answer (score 1):

To locate and `click()` on the element with text as **NEXT** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://cct-103.firebaseapp.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.MuiButton-label"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#guestName[name='guestName']"))).send_keys("Virtual107")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-contained>span.MuiButton-label"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://cct-103.firebaseapp.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='MuiButton-label']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='MuiButton-label']"))).send_keys("Virtual107")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and text()='NEXT']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```